# Shoppers on an elevator expected value

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have the following problem

[image]

My initial thought was since there was only one event happening, the expected value would be

> .5(3)

and after that failed I figured since $1.5$ shoppers leave at a given floor it would take 2 floors to empty the elevator. Both proved wrong and I am left with a final guess of the below since there would be two events of staying and leaving, both at 50%.

> .5(3) + .5(3)

This is my final attempt and I don't think I'm grasping the idea behind this very well so I would appreciate it if anyone could correct my understanding of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Start with an easier problem: what happens if we only have one shopper? Write $x_1$ for the expected number of floors taken. After $1$ floor, either he gets off immediately (so it goes up $0$ more floors), or he stays (so it goes up, on average, $x_1$ more floors). Therefore
$x_1=1+\frac12\times0+\frac12x_1,$ which gives $x_1=2$.

What if there are two shoppers? After one floor, they might both get off (probability $\frac14$, $0$ floors remaining), or one might get off (probability $\frac12$, on average there will be $x_1$ floors remaining), or they both might stay on (probability $\frac14,$ on average $x_2$ floors remaining. Thus $x_2=1+\frac12x_1+\frac14x_2.$ You already know $x_1$, so you can solve this for $x_2$, then write down a similar equation involving $x_3$ and solve that.

Answer (score 0):

If there are 3 people in the elevator the probability that after the next stop:

- 0 people are still in the elevator is ${{3}\choose{0}}(1/2)^3=1/8$
- 1 person is still in the elevator is ${{3}\choose{1}}(1/2)^2(1/2)^1=3/8$
- 2 people are still in the elevator is ${{3}\choose{2}}(1/2)^1(1/2)^2=3/8$
- 3 people are still in the elevator is ${{3}\choose{3}}(1/2)^3=1/8$

When 2 people are in the elevator, you get:

- 0 people with probability 1/4
- 1 person with probability 1/2
- 2 people with probability 1/4

So in the end you get the transition Matrix:
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0\\
1/4 & 1/2 & 1/4 & 0\\
1/8 & 3/8 & 3/8 & 1/8
\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
R & Q
\end{matrix}\right)$$
Using the a Theorem about absorbing Markov chains you get that $N=(1-Q)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty Q^n$ and $N_{i,j}$ is the mean Value of times the markov chain is in j if you started in i. And $\sum_{j=0}^3 N_{i,k}$ is the mean number of steps until absorption.
So in this case (Calculating N with matlab):
$$N=\left(\begin{matrix}2.0000     &    0    &     0\\
    1.3333  &  1.3333   &      0\\
    1.4286 &   0.5714  &  1.1429
\end{matrix}\right)$$
And since we are starting with 3 people the average number of steps until the elevator is empty is 3.1429= 1.4286 + 0.5714 + 1.1429

That is probably the easiest way to do this if you can use that Theorem.